# How to retrieve DD/MM/YY date type using "new Date().getTime()" from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, date, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an **ionic** app, using firebase as db and I want to show in the user profile, the registration date. I store the date correctly using `new Date().getTime()` when the registration happens, and the date it's stored with something like `1511786400008`. 
When I retrieve my data into my html, the date is shown like `Mon Nov 27 2017 13:40:00 GMT+0100`.

**How can I change this data into DD/MM/YY ?**

I use html/css/javascript, not java.

This is the code I use to try to retrieve the information.

**profile.ts**

```
 correct_data;
    [...]
     this.itemRef_points.orderByChild("username").equalTo(this.username).on('value',itemSnapshot =>{
    this.items_points = [];
    itemSnapshot.forEach( itemSnap => {
      this.items_points.push(itemSnap.val());
      return false;
    });
    this.items_points.forEach(i=>{
      this.correct_data = new Date(i.data_registrazione);

    })

    return this.items_points; 
  });
```

ps: "data_registrazione" it's the db node where the 1511786400008 it's stored.

**profile.html**

```
 <ion-row>
                 <div *ngFor="let item of items_points;">
                    <p><b>Email:</b> {{item.clear_email}}</p>
                    <p><b>Punti totali:</b> {{item.total_points}}</p>
                    <p><b>Punti totali:</b> {{correct_data}}</p>
                 </div>
              </ion-row>
```

Thank you to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
{{correct_data | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Also you can call toLocaleDateString() (but format will be a bit different)

```
{{correct_data.toLocaleDateString()}}
```

Comment: thank you so much! :D The first code work perfectly!!